# Connect ethereum node

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

How to configure a node and connect it to a browser so that I can perform erc20 token transactions on my site between users?

Comment: that is not easy to answer here and depends on a lot of conditions, the easiest way to interact and use erc20 Tokens is to use metamask

Comment: @MajdTL  I want to realize the ability to exchange tokens between users, how is this done on centralized exchanges, what is needed for this? The internal engine is already written, it remains to connect the ability to exchange tokens

Comment: @Ayurpwnz In a centralized exchange it is done off-chain. Every user has an entry in a database and with every exchange those balances are updated. All tokens are stored in a single wallet, and operations are recorded in the blockchain only when a user enters or exit the exchange.

Comment: @Ismael But you can’t access the main network without a node?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Centralized exchanges do have a node for deposits and withdrawals, but it is not used for trading.

Comment: @Ismael 
I understand this, I wrote above that the internal exchange engine for the exchange is written, and I need to integrate the ability to exchange data with the main network. Tell me, will there be enough nodes in fast synchronization mode, or is it necessary to do full synchronization?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz It is better to create a new question for that.